# Remove outliers from aggregated Dataframe (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, outliers

My origin dataframe looks like this, only the first rows...:

```
  categories  id products 
0          A   1       a       
1          B   1       a       
2          C   1       a       
3          A   1       b       
4          B   1       b       
5          A   2       c      
6          B   2       c
```

I aggregated it with the following code:

```
df2 = df.groupby('id').products.nunique().reset_index().merge(
pd.crosstab(df.id, df.categories).reset_index()
```

The dataframe is the following then, I added n outlier from my DF too:

```
    id products A B C
0    1       2  2 2 1    
1    2       1  1 1 0    
2    3      50  1 1 30
```

Now I am trying to remove the outliers in my new DF:

```
#remove outliners
del df2['id']
df2 = df2.loc[df2['products']<=20,[str(i) for i in df2.columns]]
```

What I then get is:

```
  products  A    B   C
0    2      NaN NaN NaN
1    1      NaN NaN NaN
```

It removes the outliers but why do I get only NaNs now in the categorie column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df2 = df2.loc[df2['products'] <= 20]
```

Comment: after reducing the code, like you've shown I don't get the NaNs any more, so now it works, thanks